# fetch records from a table to which it is having similar ids

Tags: mysql

i have two tables like

```
   uid name
    11  Cadman
    12  Clive
    13  Coleman
    14  Chester
```

and second table like

```
id      pa1 pa2 pa3 pa4
4800    11  12  11  14
4801    11  12  13  14
4802    11  12  12  
4973        12  13  14
6882    12  12  13  14
6883    11  12      14
6884    11  13  13  14
6885    11  13  13  14
```

i would like to display names instead of ids can any one help me in this query thanks in advance

Comment: Just 4 `INNER JOIN`s with the same table. You will obviously need to use different aliases.

Comment: a left join or two wouldn't kill ya. depends on the real data. If the data has nothing missing, then inner will fly

Comment: can you query it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create / Populate

```
create table nt
(   -- name table
    uid int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

create table it
(   -- id table (sorry my creativity is at a low)
    id int primary key,
    pa1 int not null,
    pa2 int not null,
    pa3 int not null,
    pa4 int not null,
    -- in the constraining kinda mood:
    CONSTRAINT fk_pa1_nt FOREIGN KEY (pa1) REFERENCES nt(uid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pa2_nt FOREIGN KEY (pa2) REFERENCES nt(uid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pa3_nt FOREIGN KEY (pa3) REFERENCES nt(uid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pa4_nt FOREIGN KEY (pa4) REFERENCES nt(uid)
);

insert nt (name) values ('kurt'),('burt'),('curt'),('dirt'),('lert'),('murte'),('qbert');
insert nt (name) values ('jim'),('kim'),('dim'),('sim'),('tim'),('Cadman'),('bim');

insert it(id,pa1,pa2,pa3,pa4) values (4800,11,12,13,14);
insert it(id,pa1,pa2,pa3,pa4) values (4801,3,5,7,9);
```

### Query

```
select it.id,nt1.name,nt2.name,nt3.name,nt4.name
from it
join nt nt1
on nt1.uid=it.pa1
join nt nt2
on nt2.uid=it.pa2
join nt nt3
on nt3.uid=it.pa3
join nt nt4
on nt4.uid=it.pa4
order by it.id;
+------+------+------+--------+------+
| id   | name | name | name   | name |
+------+------+------+--------+------+
| 4800 | sim  | tim  | Cadman | bim  |
| 4801 | curt | lert | qbert  | kim  |
+------+------+------+--------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but the data is mismatched with one column we should show null value for that column and we should show the rest of matched columns, see my question some data is missing some times

Comment: i will take a look. if there is a null then the join would not have picked it up as it wasn't an outer join. which values? i don't see what you see

Comment: Hi Drew Pierce thanks for the solution i got the idea i just used left join in your query worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name 
FROM  table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.row1 = t2.row2
INNER JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t1.row1 = t3.row3
INNER JOIN table2 AS t4 ON t1.row1 = t4.row4
INNER JOIN table2 AS t5 ON t1.row1 = t5.row5
WHERE condn;
```